# How do you call "animation_play()" from AN?

Tags: scripting, animation-nodes

When I run bpy.ops.screen.animation_play() directly from the script ("Run script" button), it plays the timeline and works fine. But if I try to run it from Animation Nodes, it gives me an error:

**"Operator bpy.ops.screen.animation_play.poll() failed. Context is incorrect."**

All I have in AN is a script node with an "integer" input (for "1" or "0" -> play or stop), then I connect an integer node to the subprogram of the script.

Here's my simple test script

```
# animStatus = 1    # only used when testing script alone

if animStatus == 1:
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()    
elif animStatus == 0:
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [poll() failed, context incorrect? - Example: bpy.ops.view3d.background\_image\_add()](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

Comment: Thanks, I had already looked at that thread, but it does not resolve my question/problem.

Comment: You should edit your question to show that. What have you tried? Why didn't the other answer help you?

Comment: Thank you. I actually just received a reply from Jacques himself, and he did confirm that what I am trying to do is not really officially possible with Animation Nodes, unfortunately. I will mark this as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not really solved, but have received confirmation from Jacques Lucke that what I am trying to do (start/stop timeline with AN) is not something that AN was designed for, and is not recommended.